# Beautiful Soup findAll() doesn't find the first one

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I'm working on a coreference-resolution system based on Neural Networks for my Bachelor's Thesis, and i have a problem when i read the corpus.

The corpus is already preproccesed, and i only need to read it to do my stuff. I use Beautiful Soup 4 to read the xml files of each document that contains the data i need.

the files look like this:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='ISO-8859-1'?>
<!DOCTYPE markables SYSTEM "markables.dtd">
<markables xmlns="www.eml.org/NameSpaces/markable">
<markable id="markable_102" span="word_390" grammatical_role="vc"  coref_set="empty"  visual="none"   rel_type="none"   np_form="indefnp"  type="" entity="NO" nb="UNK" def="INDEF"  sentenceid="19" lemmata="premia" pos="nn" head_pos="word_390" wikipedia="" mmax_level="markable"/>
<markable id="markable_15" span="word_48..word_49" grammatical_role="vc"  coref_set="empty"  visual="none"   rel_type="none"   np_form="defnp"  type="" entity="NO" nb="SG" def="DEF"  sentenceid="3" lemmata="Grozni hegoalde" pos="nnp nn" head_pos="word_48" wikipedia="Grozny" mmax_level="markable"/>
<markable id="markable_101" span="word_389" grammatical_role="sbj"  coref_set="set_21"  coref_type="named entities"  visual="none"   rel_type="coreferential"  sub_type="exact repetition"   np_form="ne_o"  type="enamex" entity="LOC" nb="SG" def="DEF" sentenceid="19" lemmata="Mosku" pos="nnp" head_pos="word_389" wikipedia="" mmax_level="markable"/>
...
```

i need to extract all the spans here, so try to do it with this code (python3):

```
...
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
...
file1 = markables+filename+"_markable_level.xml"
xml1 = open(file1) #markable

soup1 = BeautifulSoup(xml1, "html5lib") #markable
...
...
for markable in soup1.findAll('markable'):
    try:
        span = markable.contents[1]['span']
        print(span)
        spanA = span.split("..")[0]
        spanB = span.split("..")[-1]
...
```

(I ignored most of the code, as they are 500 lines)

```
python3 aurreprozesaketaSTM.py
train
--- 28.329787254333496 seconds ---
&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&       egun.06-1-p0002500.2000-06-01.europa
word_48..word_49
word_389
word_385..word_386
word_48..word_52
...
```

if you conpare the xml file with the output, you can see that word_390 is missing.

I get almost all the data that i need, then preproccess everything, build the system with neural networks, and finally i get scores and all...

But as I loose the first word of each document, my systems accuracy is a bit lower than what should be.

Can anyone help me with this? Any idea where is the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are parsing XML with html5lib. It is not supported for parsing XML.

> lxml’s XML parser ... The only currently supported XML parser

https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#installing-a-parser

Comment: True. I read somewhere that html5lib works with xml, so i tried it (as it didn't have any dependencies), and as it looked like it was working correctly at first, i forgot about it. i will try with lxml, and see if that solves the problem. Thanks for the fast answer!

Comment: You were right! it was a problem of the parser. with lxml and some changes the problem is solved, i'm just checking if everything else is working with the change, but this problem is solved. Thanks!